# node.js synchronus call with asyc waterfall module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying following code

```
async.waterfall([
  a1, b1, c1  
], function (err, result) {

});
function a1(callback){
// long processing external call 
    setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('delayed str');
}, 5000);
    callback(null, 'one', 'two');
}
function b1(arg1, arg2, callback){
    console.log(arg1)
    callback(null, 'three');
}
function c1(arg1, callback){
    console.log(arg1)

    callback(null, 'done');
}
```

I am expecting following output

```
delayed str
one
three
```

But I got following output

```
one
three
delayed str
```

How can I achieve proper synchronous function calls using nodejs async module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your `callback(null, 'one', 'two');` call into the timeout in order to call the next function after the timeout period:

```
async.waterfall([
    a1, b1, c1  
], function (err, result) {

});
function a1(callback){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('delayed str'); 
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    }, 5000);
}
function b1(arg1, arg2, callback){
    console.log(arg1)
    callback(null, 'three');
}
function c1(arg1, callback){
    console.log(arg1)
    callback(null, 'done');
}
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out, also your solution seems working,
but actually I used `setTimeout` in question for example; 
so my question is if I use long processing function instead of `setTimeout` then also this will work?

Comment: As long as you make your `callback()` as the last part of that function.  It only shifts to the next function in the series when you make that `callback()`.  Think of them like instruction to proceed to the next function.

Comment: I am using `callback()` at end of function only, I am using external `model` file to query so I think calling `callback()` from models file is not possible.

Comment: My 2 cents - instead of naming the function `callback`, name it `next` and then it makes sense to call it once you are ready to move on to the next operation, ie the current function is done executing.

Comment: You can pass your callback function to the model and have that model call your `callback()` function when it completes its business.  Because Node is non-blocking you may find yourself having to think a little differently and more creatively to make things synchronous.

Comment: @Ding one more question, I have several nested synchronous functions; so what is preferable `nested waterfall` functions or single centralised `waterfall` function

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have 3 main interdependent functions, and in those functions there are other small functions; currently I kept only one outer`async.waterfall([])` and for those 3 functions I am planning to use another `async.waterfall([])` to make them synchronous. So my question is should keep current flow or should I use only one outer  `async.waterfall([])` and write all function one after another?

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at your code and understanding your intentions, but I'd opt for whatever works right and looks cleanest.